# Javascript: Created element with attributes in JS not read by function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

supposing I have 5 checkboxes that I created manually through HTML, all of which have the attributes; Name, Type and Value. All of those checkboxes, when checked triggers an event which allows a button to be enabled. (Code below)

```
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.is(':checked')) {
            $("#deleteModalTrigger").prop("disabled",false);
        } else {
            $("#deleteModalTrigger").prop("disabled",true);
        }
    });
```

Now, I create another checkbox through javascript and append it to a row in a table. It appears in the view, but checking it does not trigger the code above even though it is also a checkbox.

```
            var column1 = document.createElement('td');
            var cb1 = document.createElement('input');
            cb1.type="checkbox";
            cb1.name="foo";
            cb1.value="Something-cbvalue-0";
            column1.setAttribute("rowspan","2");
            column1.appendChild(cb1);
            row.appendChild(column1);
```

Any help is appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as the checkbox is added dynamically after the dom is loaded

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
```

this click event is not binded to the newly added element
try using

```
$(document).on('click','input[type="checkbox"]',function() {
```

Comment: Thank you sir! That worked :) SO says I can't accept your answer as correct for 11 more minutes. I will mark it as correct once the time is up. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

You Can use the on function to get the change event of newly created checkbox. Inside that function you can check the checked property and make the target button as enabled or disabled.

$(document).on('change','yourCheckboxID',function(){

```
    if($(this).prop('checked'))
      {

            //Disable or enable the button

      }

})
```